# how to recreate route from overviewpath?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Im trying to recreate a route that i saved on my database using all its geopoints, and I am trying to use the direction Rederer to do so

```
function addOldRoute(){
    var waypts =[];
    for ( var int = 0; int < elems.length; int++) {
        if(int !=0 && int!=elems.lenght-1){
            waypts.push(getWaypoint(elems[int]));
        }
    }

       var request = {
              origin: new google.maps.LatLng(elems[0].latLng.lat(),elems[0].latLng.lng()),
              destination: new google.maps.LatLng(elems[elems.length-1].latLng.lat(),elems[elems.length-1].latLng.lng()),
              waypoints: waypts,
              optimizeWaypoints: true,
              travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
          };

       directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
                addPontos();
                if (directionsDisplay.getMap() == null) {
                    directionsDisplay.setMap(mapAddRota);
                }
            }
        });
}

function getWaypoint(elem){
    return {
        location:new google.maps.LatLng(elem.latLng.lat(), elem.latLng.lng()),
        stopover:true
    };
}
```

The route doesn't and I get a Message telling me that Maximum wypoints exceeded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum number of waypoints in a single directions request with the [free API is 8](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints):

> The maximum allowed waypoints is 8, plus the origin, and destination. Maps API for Business 
>   customers are allowed 23 waypoints, plus the origin, and destination. Waypoints are not 
>   supported for transit directions.

If you have "all the geopoints", you don't need the directions service, you can just draw the polyline.  If the original directions request didn't include waypoints, then you should be able to recreate it with just the origin and destination (the endpoints of your saved route), if it did include waypoints, you will need to save them as well.

Note that the "overviewpath" (which is in the title, but not the question), does not always include "all the geopoints" necessary to completely follow the roads.